# Remove node function on parent element

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS. I'm trying to delete the parent node with all the children by clicking a button. But the console tells me that undefined is not a function. What am I missing?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vy0d8bqt/

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="output">Get contacts</button>
        <button type="button" id="clear_contacts">clear contact</button>
        <div id="output_here"></div>
```

JS:

```
// contact book, getting data from JSON and outputting via a button

            // define a JSON structure
            var contacts = {
                "friends" :
                [
                    {
                    "name" : "name1",
                    "surname" : "surname1"
                    },
                    {
                    "name" : "name2",
                    "surname" : "surname2"
                }
                ]
            };

            //get button ID and id of div where content will be shown
            var get_contacts_btn = document.getElementById("output");
            var output = document.getElementById("output_here");
            var clear = document.getElementById("clear_contacts");
            var i;
            // get length of JSON

            var contacts_length = contacts.friends.length;

            get_contacts_btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                //console.log("clicked");
                for(i = 0; i < contacts_length; i++){
                var data = contacts.friends[i];
                var name = data.name;
                var surname = data.surname;
                output.style.display = 'block';
                output.innerHTML += "<p> name: " + name + "| surname: " + surname + "</p>";



                }
            });

            //get Children of output div to remove them on clear button 
           //get output to clear

           output_to_clear = document.getElementById("output_here");


            clear.addEventListener('click', function(){
                output_to_clear.removeNode(true);
            });
```

Comment: Or maybe you want `innerHTML = ''` to be able to display info again? http://jsfiddle.net/vy0d8bqt/2/

Comment: Well, `removeNode` simply doesn't exist. Why do you think it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `remove()` instead of `removeNode()`

http://jsfiddle.net/vy0d8bqt/1/

However, this also removes the `output_to_clear` node itself. You can use `output_to_clear.innerHTML = ''` if you like to just delete all content of the node, but not removing the node itself (so you can click 'get contacts' button again after clearing it)

http://jsfiddle.net/vy0d8bqt/3/

Answer (score 1):

You want this for broad support:

```
output_to_clear.parentNode.removeChild(output_to_clear);
```

---

Or this in modern browsers only:

```
output_to_clear.remove();
```

---

But either way, make sure you don't try to remove it after it has already been removed. Since you're caching the reference, that could be an issue, so this may be safer:

```
if (output_to_clear.parentNode != null) {
    output_to_clear.remove();
}
```

---

If you were hoping to empty its content, then do this:

```
while (output_to_clear.firstChild) {
    output_to_clear.removeChild(output_to_clear.firstChild); 
}
```

Comment: Is `remove()` standard? Firefox defines it in `Element.prototype`, but I can't find it in [DOM Level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-745549614), nor in MDN docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think using jQuery's $.remove() is probably the best choice here.  If you can't or don't want to use jQuery, [The Mozilla docs for Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#Remove_all_children_nested_within_a_node) provides a function to remove all child nodes.

```
Element.prototype.removeAll = function () {
  while (this.firstChild) { this.removeChild(this.firstChild); }
  return this;
};
```

Which you would use like:

```
output_to_clear.removeAll();
```

For a one-off given the example provided:

```
while (output_to_clear.firstChild) { output_to_clear.removeChild(output_to_clear.firstChild); }
```